# importing numpy on an ARM processor

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I have python 2.4 installed on an ARM processor and have moved all of the libraries I need onto this machine including those for numpy 1.6.2 When I try to import numpy, I get the following:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in ?
import add_newdocs
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in ?
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in ?
from type_check import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in ?
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in ?
import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I try to see if the file exists I get:

```
# ls /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/core/ | grep multi
multiarray.so
```

I'm pretty new to python in general and don't know why I'm getting this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, but did you compile it for your ARM machine (or downloaded ARM binaries)? Or maybe there are some problems with the user rights?

Comment: I haven't compiled it for the ARM machine. After looking into it more I think that's the most likely problem. I haven't had to cross compile before, any good sources on how to proceed doing this with numpy?

Answer (score 2):

this is indeed the first error you have when you are trying to import numpy with binaries for the wrong architecture.

some inspiration for compiling to arm : https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android